# achieve tree view like structure in iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to achieve tree like structure as shown in below image on my iPhone App

Package 1 =>
       Packg 1.1
             Package 1.1.1
             Package 1.1.2
       Packg 1.2

Its like user received Package having 3 bottles send by vendors. Either vendor has package each bottle as sub package or directly all three bottles within single package. Individual bottle is termed as Item and Package as Packages.

There is Package0010 as main package and depending on bottle packaging we either subdivide as three sub package having 1 item each. or two sub package(two item) and one separate item so total 3 Item or bottles.

How I can achieve above structure.
Note I am using `UILable`, `UITexfield`, `UITexfield` with tags. I can not use `UITableview` ...

just idea if anyone came across such problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use RATreeView component for similar tasks. It is used *like* UITableView with datasource and delegate protocols, and it is highly customisable.

https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView

Comment: hello, thank you for the reply. i downloaded RATreeView , tried to run sample basic example , added RATree class but it not working .... cocoapod i am totally new to this

Comment: Just  copy files from it into your project - RATreeView.h and RATreeView.m No need to use pod.

Comment: Thank you so much, will customise for my need... :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many samples available on cocoa controls. You can refer following link ;

[Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=expandable)

You can use any of following example;

1) [Example 1](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/skstableview)

2) [Example 2](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ratreeview)

3) [Example 3](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/expandablerows)

All these use **UITableView's** *delegate* and *datasource* methods, so you can easily integrate and modify it accordingly your requirements.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hello, thank you for the reply. i downloaded RATreeView , tried to run sample basic example , added RATree class but it not working .... cocoapod i am totally new to this

Answer (score 0):

I use [SwiftListTreeDataSource](https://github.com/dzmitry-antonenka/SwiftListTreeDataSource) to visualise hierarchical data structures (trees) in lists-like way. It's UI agnostic, just like view-model, so you can use it with UITableView/UICollectionView/NSTableView or even SwiftUI with search feature.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I designed a simple treeView in swift.**

You can see the code in my [GitHub](https://github.com/shamiul110107/TreeView-iOS)

[image]